# Accidentally deleted user, lost all user permission/privilege to sudo

Tags: linux, linux-mint, sudo, authentication, privileges

This is my fourth day in Linux OS from windows.

I don't know why I did it, but I enter this command `sudo deluser <MYUSER> sudo`. After entering the command, I lost all my `sudo` privileges. And every time I enter a command with `sudo` this message appears in the next line. I also have no any backup.

```
Sorry, user <user> is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/apt-get update' as root on <HOST>
```

I thought about reformatting my PC just to reset all privileges, but I can't. Though my password is working in desktop login screen, my pw isn't working on here.

[image]

I'm also seeing a warning here saying `A problem has been detected with your thumbnail cache. Fixing it will require administrative privileges.`. When clicking `Fix now`, authenticate pop up appears, as stated above my password isn't working.

[image]

I can't just throw away my ssd because I messed up. If I could just reformat my OS. Please help me, anyone.

Comment: Root password is not your user password. If you do not know this, you can boot right into a root shell and reset it: https://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/09/02/reset-forgotten-passwords-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: I don't know this. I'll try this now. Thanks for your answer @Panki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't delete your user, by specifying both user and group in the `deluser` command, you only removed yourself from the *sudo* group. And because membership in this group allows you to use `sudo`, you can no longer use it.

All you need to do is to login as root and add yourself back. You probably don't have a root password set (that is default on Ubuntu/Mint) so you'll need to reset it.  [This question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) has a nice tutorial for resetting the root password. And after this you just need to login as root in a terminal using `su` and add yourself back to the *sudo* group using `usermod -a -G sudo <user>`.