I have only one user is my linux pc. I deleted myself from sudo user. How to add myself back?
I entered command "sudo deluser myusername sudo", just out of curiosity. I was the only root user and this deleted myself from root user.
Now I can't add back myself because I deleted my root permission. How to make myself root user again.  Also I am not able to execute sudo command because my pc has no root user now.please help.

Did you happen to set a root password? For the actual user root?

Yes I have root password but I am not able to execute any command as root because I am not a root user now. Beacuse I deleted root permission of only user present in PC.

@udaybadhani I think you're confusing two things. "root" is an actual user on your system. You mean you can't do things as root because you can't run things using sudo, right?

try booting into single user mode

@MarcusMüller yes i cant run things using sudo

Could you update your post with your linux distribution?  In this particular case, it matters because sudo behaves differently depending on your distribution and sometimes your version.

@eyoung100 I just found an exect same question. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617788/accidentally-deleted-user-lost-all-user-permission-privilege-to-sudo    my problem is very much similar  to this

@udaybadhani Do exactly what the selected answer says.  Enable the real root account by setting root's password, login as root and re-add your user to the sudo group.  This is the reason I asked you to add your distribution yo your question.

That's a duplicate, yes?
